# Backup up database to compressed local folder - what will be the performance implication?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, windows-server

I have sql server 2016 web edition on Windows 2016 server VM.

I want to backup the database, to a folder on a local drive (SSD) - please don't ask why, long story.

Due to the size of the DBs, and comparatively small size of disk, I want to back up to a compressed folder.

What would be the performance implications? Will they be noticeable? (VM with 16 cores, 128GB ram, typically cpu utalization ~ 20%)

Looking for some suggestions based on experience

Answer (score 2):

Don't backup to a compressed folder.  There are supportability problems for SQL Server with compressed folders.  See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/231347/description-of-support-for-sql-server-databases-on-compressed-volumes).  Take a [compressed backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-compression-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) instead.

Comment: Hmm... I first link seems to talk about storing the database on compressed folder. Does this also imply that the backup it self cannot be stored in compressed folder?

And I seem to recall that web edition did not have compressed backups...

Comment: confirmed, Web Edition does not support compressed backups https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Looks like the backup is fine "SQL Server backups to compressed volumes can save disk space. However, they may increase CPU usage during the backup operation. We always recommend that you use the BACKUP checksum facilities to help guarantee data integrity."